# I need to print a variable number of chars as hex in an embedded system for debugging

Tags: c, printf, hexdump

In C I need to print a variable number of chars as hex in an embedded system for debugging.  As this is part of a debug trace macro I want to avoid loops or other logic that `printf` can't handle.  I also don't want to declare any new variables to prevent Heisenbug issues.  Output space is also an issue so I want to dump it in hex.

```
uint8_t* buffer;
uint8_t length;

MakeString(*message, &buffer, &length);  //Function that puts some values in buffer and sets length
```

I'm looking for a printf  that can take buffer and length to produce something like:

```
0x1A1B1C0A02
```

for values of {1A,1B,1C,0A,02} and length = 5

I know that `%.*s` or `%*` can handle size variables.  Is there any way to do this without a for/while loop?

Comment: what is the type of *message? how it its length determined?

Comment: As an alternative you can write your own "complex function with loops" in a separate .c file, and then to use the macro to call it. In the debug version the macro must call the function, and in the release version it must do nothing.

Comment: Unless you are using an in-circuit hardware emulator there is NO WAY to avoid the Heisenbug. If you add anything to your faulty code, you could move the evidential side-effects of your bug elsewhere, or make it a benign bug. You might not want to declare new variables but you won't avoid using the stack.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko function parameters are local variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've use stuff like the following in the past:

```
void
to_hex(char *output, size_t out_len, uint8_t const *input, size_t in_len)
{
        static const char digits[] = "0123456789abcdef";
        if (out_len < 1) {
                return;
        }

        --out_len; /* reserve space for that NUL terminator */
        while (out_len > 1 && in_len) {
                *output++ = digits[(*input & 0xF0) >> 4];
                *output++ = digits[*input & 0x0F];
                out_len -= 2;
                ++input, --in_len;
        }
        if (in_len) {
                *output++ = digits[(*input & 0xF0) >> 4];
        }
        *output = '\0';
}
```

The only memory that it is uses is static and const so it is usually allocated in the BSS.  If you have a memory-mapped output device, then you can simplify this and omit the output buffer and write directly to the memory location.  You could optimize this a lot more and hide it behind a macro so you can omit it in release builds.

The systems that I worked on didn't have a `printf` or `sprintf` implementation, so we usually rolled our own hex dump code.

Comment: I guess he missed the `while` in there.

Comment: @Jasen ... I was surprised when this got accepted as well.  I guess that unrolling the loop is pretty trivial if you constrain the input length.

Answer (score 1):

no.

I guess you could hang something of the serial port buffer emoty interrupt  that reads a byte from a buffer and emits two bytes on the serial port... no loops *per se*.

or do something vile like this (this example valid only for length 0 to 10)

```
int printbuf(unsigned char*buffer,int length)
{
     #define b(x) buffer[x<length?x:0]
     return printf("%02h%02h%02h%02h%02h%02h%02h%02h%02h%02h%02h"+4*(10-length)
           ,b(0),b(1),b(2),b(3),b(4),b(5),b(6),b(7),b(8),b(9));
     #undef b
}
```

but sprintf itself contains loops...